# Как поменять кодировку в phpMyAdmin 2.5.6?

Tags: кодировка, utf-8, php, mysql

Вот уже час смотрю в главное окно программы **phpMyAdmin 2.5.6** и не могу найти, где там можно **поменять кодировку** с **windows-1251** на **utf-8**. Помогите, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это не оно?

[image: Смена кодировки]

Comment: Оно по сути, только видимо у меня phpmyadmin настолько древний был, снёс его скачал новый! Всем спасибо!

Comment: Именно оно :)

Answer (score 1):

Там же как раз на главной странице: "Сопоставление соединения с MySQL:". И рядом select со списком выбора кодировок.

Comment: Ну нету... реально, главная страница адрес такой: http://localhost/phpMyAdmin/ ... Верно?

Comment: Вроде верно. Как вообще выглядит эта страница? Что на ней присутствует? Какая версия пхпадмина?